# How to prevent dynamic content that contain html tag that can messed up the page style / template

Tags: html, css, templates

For example, I have a page that has HTML like this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <!-- Dynamic content here that can contain html tags -->
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <!-- Dynamic content here that can contain html tags -->
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <!-- Dynamic content here that can contain html tags -->
    </div>
</div>
```

is there a simple solution to prevent this "Dynamic content" to messed up my page HTML template.

For example, if the "Dynamic Content" contain HTML div tag that does not have a closing div tag, then my page template/style will be broken because of this "Dynamic Content"

Comment: you could try it with an `<iframe>` in your divs

Answer (score 0):

Usually for some servers if minor mistakes like this happen in html/css/script it automatically neglects it and displays the design as we expect.
Note: it happens sometimes for some servers.

But for some servers, even a div is not closed or bracket is not closed properly it shows server error.

In general, it is better to design the html section separately in any editor and then update it dynamically.

Better to avoid these issues at initial stage...